# How can I prevent CakePHP from escaping data on a save?

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, postgis

I am doing some PostGIS work on a CakePHP application.

Because I've been working with some database functions, I've done raw `$this->query()` calls to do inserts of data. I'm at a point where I need to get the ID of the result of an insert query, but `$this->query()`  returns an empty array.

Here is the query I'm using for inserts:

```
INSERT INTO locations (title,company_id,state_id,poly,point) 
VALUES ('$title',$company_id,$state_id,ST_GeomFromText('$geom',4269),$point);
```

The problem is Cake is trying to insert `'ST_GeomFromText('$geom',4269)'` as a string, and I cannot figure out how to get it to remove the quotes in the SQL insert statement it prepares via `$this->Location->save();`.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Before I was doing `$this->query();` and my SQL works fine. That's not the issue.

Now when I do:

```
$this->Location->create();
$this->Location->set('poly',$poly);

... Set all the rest of the model fields ...

$this->Location->save();
```

The SQL that gets produced looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO locations (title,company_id,state_id,poly,point) 
VALUES ('Some Title',5,23,'ST_GeomFromText('$geom',4269)',POINT(-72.342,102.23455);
```

Because ST_GeomFromText gets 'quoted', PostgreSQL throws an error and doesn't insert the geometry.

Comment: Take a look at the atomic query wrapper updateAll() in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem turned out to NOT be a CakePHP based one, but a PostgreSQL one!

By appending "RETURNING id" to the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO locations (title,company_id,state_id,poly,point) 
VALUES ('$title',$company_id,$state_id,ST_GeomFromText('$geom',4269),$point) RETURNING id;
```

The query no longer returns an empty array, and now returns the ID of the row it just created!

Answer (score 0):

Via `$this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();` you are able to get the last inserted ID. So, after a save you can call this code to get its id.