# How to Save IP address By INET_ATON in CakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to use MySQL `INET_ATON` function to save IP address by CakePHP 2.x?
My code is here and not work correctly!

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
$data = array();
$ip = '8.8.8.8';
$data['ip'] = 'INET_ATON('.$ip.')';
$this->MyModel->save($data);
```

And i do not use `$this->MyModel->query()`.

For Example:

```
$this->MyModel->query("INSERT INTO `my_table` (`ip`) VALUES (INET_ATON('8.8.8.8'))")
```

Comment: I don't know Cake, but that is unlikely to work - it will assume that is a string, not a SQL function. Is there a method in the ORM to set a column to an unescaped entity, like a column or a function?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723248/how-can-i-prevent-cakephp-from-escaping-data-on-a-save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use This Code. Correctly Work.

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
$data = array();
$ip = '8.8.8.8';
$data['MyModel']['ip'] = DboSource::expression('INET_ATON("'.$ip.'")');
$this->MyModel->save($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ip2long function for converting ip to int and it saves in your Db like this:

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
$data = array();
$ip = '8.8.8.8';
$data['MyModel']['ip'] = ip2long($ip);
$this->MyModel->save($data);
```

Thanks..!

Comment: I Want To Use MySQL Functions. Not Only INET_ATON Function.